# SQL - Update all rows with certain condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi i want to do is a query which do the following thing:

If i execute the query ,all rows will set to 0 except certain id in the where(which supposed to be always 1 and only one row can be active at the moment)

**tbl_menu**
id | serial
starter | varchar
plate | varchar
beverage | varchar
status | smallint

So if i have one registry with status in 1 and everything else in 0, when i execute this query, certain id i choose will change to 1 and the others to 0
also only one row status = 1

Comment: `i don't know how can i explain it` ... then we don't know how we can answer it.  I can imagine several ways of explaining why that `1` value is shifting, but without knowing your logic it would be speculation at best.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
check below the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tbl_menu
set status = CASE WHEN id = 4 or status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Comment: But it can be only one record with status = 1

Comment: I have updated the query according to your columns. If your `id` column is primary key, this query will work. Just update 4 with any `id` value that you want to set 1

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Comment: if you add "where id = 4 or status = 1" you only update the two rows you need to rather than all rows.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic update statement. But if you could give more info on the column names and on what condition you want to do the updates it would be helpful.

```
UPDATE tbl_menu SET (column) = value  
WHERE (condition)
```

Comment: How does it guarantee that only one record is active?  Or you're suggesting two separate statements?

Comment: @JimJones I just wrote the basic update statement. The above statement can be modified according to the condition and the condition determines if it would update multiple rows. It is difficult to answer unless the condition is specific.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two choices with the design as it is.
1) Do it with two easy queries.
2) Write one more complicated query with a case statement.

I personally like easy:

```
UPDATE tblmenu SET status = 0 WHERE status = 1;
UPDATE tblmenu SET status = 1 WHERE id = n;
```

Although, having said that, I think a better approach is this...

- Get rid of your status column
- Create a new table called, say tblstatus with one column id
- One record with the id of the record
- Foreign key to your main table

Now all you have to do is:

```
UPDATE tblstatus SET id = n;
```

Faster, easier, more robust...

Comment: Not working, it ignores the second query when i use those in a function

Comment: Well, given that you haven't shared what you've tried I can't help you with "not working". Anyway, I strongly recommend you do the redesign I suggest - it is a much better solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve the problem of the *update*, but it does solve the problem of enforcing that (at most) one row is active.  Use a partial unique index:

```
create unique index unq_menu_active on tblmenu(flag) where flag = 1;
```